# My android app is not installing on my emulator

Tags: android

I have ran this application this app on my emulator on various ocassions but surpisingly it just stoped installing now. When I run I dont see the app intalled on the emulator. The console message is below:

```
[2013-09-26 12:03:58 -JackHealthCare] ------------------------------
[2013-09-26 12:03:58 - JackHealthCare] Android Launch!
[2013-09-26 12:03:58 - JackHealthCare] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-26 12:03:58 - JackHealthCare] Performing com.example.jackhealthcare.SplashActivity activity launch
[2013-09-26 12:03:59 - JackHealthCare] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'. 
[2013-09-26 12:05:05 - JackHealthCare] Performing com.example.jackhealthcare.SplashActivity activity launch
[2013-09-26 12:05:08 - JackHealthCare] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'GingerbreadApi' 
[2013-09-26 12:05:28 - JackHealthCare] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-09-26 12:05:28 - JackHealthCare] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched... 
[2013-09-26 12:06:48 - JackHealthCare] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.jackealthcare.SplashActivity activity launch'!
[2013-09-26 12:15:02 - JackHealthCare] ------------------------------
[2013-09-26 12:15:02 - JackHealthCare] Android Launch!
[2013-09-26 12:15:02 - JackHealthCare] adb is running normally. 
[2013-09-26 12:15:02 - JackHealthCare] Performing com.example.jackhealthcare.SplashActivity activity launch 
[2013-09-26 12:15:03 - JackHealthCare] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'. 
[2013-09-26 12:16:38 - JackHealthCare] Performing com.example.jackhealthcare.SplashActivity activity launch
[2013-09-26 12:16:42 - JackHealthCare] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'GingerbreadApi' 
[2013-09-26 12:16:49 - JackHealthCare] New emulator found: emulator-5554 
[2013-09-26 12:16:49 - JackHealthCare] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched... 
[2013-09-26 12:18:05 - JackHealthCare] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.jackhealthcare.SplashActivity activity launch'!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[2013-09-26 12:15:03 - RhemaHealthCare] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'.
```

Create a new Android virtual device , select the Target as Google API - API Level x.

Answer (score 3):

You must be using Google API's in your application.

`Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'.`

You need to create an AVD with Google API's installed.

See:
https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing

Comment: Thans alot I have solved the problem. The emulator that I was using add Google Api stalled on it. I simply deleted the old one and I recreated it. The problem was solved. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed your app on AVD but without google API

You should create Google API AVD for running your application..

NOTE: Whenever you run application in which you integrate map then use **Google API AVD**